# How to create Mustache template for nested objects with dynamic key name

Tags: mustache

I have an object with the below structure

```
{
  id1: {
    name: 'name1',
    value: 'value1'
  },
  id2: {
    name: 'name2',
    value: 'value2'
  },
  ...
}
```

because the key value is the id of nested objects and it's dynamically generated, I can not use dot notations of nested blocks like:

```
{{#item}}
  {{id.value}}
  {{id.name}}
{{/item}}
```

or

```
{{#item}}
  {{#id}}
    {{value}}
    {{name}}
  {{/id}}
{{/item}}
```

How to write a template representing these nested objects?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to convert this type of dynamic json to an array while preserving the dynamic keys if we want to show it in template(storing these dynamic keys `id1, id2, id3` in a fixed key like `id`)

```
var obj = {
  id1: {
    name: 'name1',
    value: 'value1'
  },
  id2: {
    name: 'name2',
    value: 'value2'
  },

  id3: {
    name: 'name3',
    value: 'value3'
  }
};

var arr=[];
for(var i in obj ){
    var o = obj[i];
    //if you want to preserve ids
    o.id = i;
    arr.push(obj[i]);
}
```

In mustache template we can use it like this.

```
{{#arr}}
    {{name}}
    {{value}}
    {{id}}
 {{/arr}}
```